# convert data.frame to data.table column missing

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Had a case like this.  Tried to convert "mtcars" class from data.frame to data.table.

"mtcars" data:

```
> mtcars
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Original class is "data.frame".

```
> str(mtcars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Convert to data.table. Found the Column for car brands are gone.  Why?  How to retain the column of brands?

```
> mtcars2 <- data.table(mtcars)
> mtcars2
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Would like to have a data.table with final data format as below -- having a NEW column name "Brands" for the first column of brands.  How to code to add the column "Brands" from the original "mtcars" dataset?

```
Brands              mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the rownames that are missing, not one of the columns.

If you want Brands as a column, the manual approach is:

```
data.table(Brands = rownames(mtcars), mtcars)
```

---

Alternately:

```
data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE)
```

However, this does not make the resulting data.table have the old rownames, it just makes a column for them, called "rn". This is in the documentation, `?data.table`.

---

Alternately, modify the table in place, for `DF = mtcars`:

```
setDT(DF, keep.rownames = "Brands")
```

*Minor point:* we cannot `setDT(mtcars, ...)`, since `mtcars` is a built-in table.

Comment: For the alternative, you can also write `data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = "Brands")` if you want to choose another name than default "rn". (CRAN version 1.10.4 of `data.table` used).

Comment: @UweBlock Testing on 1.10.5, that doesn't create the Brands column. It does work for setDT, though... I'm editing that in. Thanks